# passport.js req.user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm building a nodejs app with express and using passport for authentication. I'm a relative beginner to the platform having only worked with it for 3 weeks. I'm running into problems as my server does not save the user information.

I can login correctly using MongoDB as my database source. The information is fetched correctly from the database, and it appears to validate correctly with passport. However, the information does not persist and req.user is undefined upon redirect.

I've tried for hours reordering middleware having searched other questions and answers but nothing seems to be working! I really don't know what's wrong.

**app.js**
`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const passport = require('passport');
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const mongo = require('./controllers/mongo');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(require('express-useragent').express());



app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret : 'secret',
    resave : true,
    saveUninitialized : true
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use((req,res,next)=> {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error  = req.flash('error');
    next();
})
    
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
    



//router
const router = express.Router();

async function start_app() {
    await mongo.init();
    require("./controllers/passport")(passport);
    require("./controllers/gameio")(io);

    
    
    app.use('/forums', require('./routes/forums'));
    app.use('/user', require('./routes/users'));
    app.use('/tournaments', require('./routes/tournaments'));
    app.use('/members', require('./routes/memberlist'));
    app.use('/profile', require('./routes/profile'));
    app.use('/lobby', require('./routes/lobby'));
    app.use('/game', require('./routes/game'));
    app.use('/watch', require('./routes/watch'));

}
start_app();


const server = http.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
module.exports = router;
```

`

**passport configuration**
`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { dbo } = require('../controllers/mongo');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({usernameField : 'email'},async function(email,password,done) {
            //match user
            await dbo.getUser({userEmail : email})
                .then((user)=>{
                if(!user) {
                   return done(null,false,{message : 'that email is not registered'});
                }
                
                console.log(user); // returns the relevant chunk of the user table fetched
                
                //match pass
                bcrypt.compare(password,user.userPassword,(err,isMatch)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;

                    if(isMatch) {
                        return done(null,user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null,false,{message : 'pass incorrect'});
                    }
                })
            })
            .catch((err)=> {console.log(err)})
        })
        
    )
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log(user); // returns the relevant chunk of the user table fetched
        
        done(null, user);
    });
      
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        done(null, null);
    }); 
}; 
`
```

**user login page**
`

```
router.post('/login',(req,res,next)=>{
passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect : '/forums',
        failureRedirect : '/user/login',
        failureFlash : true,
    })(req,res,next);
 })
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializeUser` determines which data of the user object should be stored in the session and `deserializeUser` The first argument of deserializeUser corresponds to the key of the user object that was given to the done function, so do like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```